# instanceof compiletime error when and why?

Tags: java

Below given code compiles:

```
class Robot { }  
interface Animal { }  
class Feline implements Animal { }  
public class BarnCat extends Feline {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        Animal af = new Feline();  
        Feline ff = new Feline();  
        BarnCat b = new BarnCat();  
        Robot r = new Robot();  
        if(af instanceof Animal) System.out.print("1 ");  
        if(af instanceof BarnCat) System.out.print("2 ");  
        if(b instanceof Animal) System.out.print("3 ");  
        if(ff instanceof BarnCat) System.out.print("4 ");  
        if(r instanceof Animal) System.out.print("5 ");  
    }  
}
```

and this one will throw compile time error

```
public class One{  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  

        One o = new One();  
        if(o instanceof Two) {  
           System.out.println("Yes");  
        } else {  
            System.out.println("No");  
        }  
    }  
 }  
 class Two{}
```

Why is it so? Both the case quite similar in nature?

Comment: What do you think it's supposed to do? This works: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/examples/InstanceofDemo.java

Comment: if you check 2nd code block it will not compile. Reason in convertible types. In first one also Robert class has nothing to do with whole inheritance hierarchic still it is not throwing compile time error

Answer (score 3):

[`instanceof`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) makes the check at **runtime**. However, the compiler can tell at the compilation time that this is not true, it's smart :)

See [15.20.2. Type Comparison Operator instanceof](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2):

> If a cast of the RelationalExpression to the ReferenceType would be
>   rejected as a compile-time error, **then the instanceof relational
>   expression likewise produces a compile-time error**. In such a
>   situation, the result of the instanceof expression could never be true.

Comment: if you check 2nd code block it will not compile. Reason in convertible types. In first one also Robert class has nothing to do with whole inheritance hierarchic still it is not throwing compile time error

Answer (score 2):

Because compilator is smart enough to know, that there is NO possibility, that the instance `o` can be class `Two` in any possible way.

Therefore this `if` statement makes no sense, because it always returns false.

For example, both classes `One` and `Two` extends basic class `Object`. You can do something like this :

```
One one = new One();
Two two = new Two();

Object o1 = one;
Object o2 = two;

if (o1 instanceof One) { ... }
```

This make sense, because if you save instance to variable which type is ancestor of that instance, it is not absolutely clear, if that `Object` is `One` or `Two` or any other class

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible that the object `o` is an `instanceof` class Two. If `Two extends One` then the compilation error will be fixed.

Comment: In first code block Robert is also not extending any of the class still it is allowing compilation.!..here if I add Two extends One then only it is allowing to compile.!!

Answer (score 0):

The *static type* of `o` is known to be `One`. The compiler knows that a `One` object *can not be* a `Two` object (because `Two` is "another hierarchy).

It *would* be possible if `Two` where an interface or a class derived from `One`.

Comment: I got it but why first code block compiled? it is also quite similar to second one where Robert is not in inheritance class Hierarchic

Answer (score 0):

Class Two is not related to Class one is any manner.No common interface or inheritance relationship exist between class one and class two.So it will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

From [jls-15.20.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2)

The type of the RelationalExpression operand of the `instanceof` operator must be a reference type or the null type; otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.

**It is a compile-time error if the ReferenceType mentioned after the instanceof operator does not denote a reference type that is reifiable (§4.7).**

If a cast of the RelationalExpression to the ReferenceType would be rejected as a compile-time error, then the `instanceof` relational expression likewise produces a compile-time error. In such a situation, the result of the `instanceof` expression could never be true.

```
class Point   { int x, y; }
class Element { int atomicNumber; }
class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Point   p = new Point();
    Element e = new Element();
    if (e instanceof Point) {  // compile-time error (you are checking o instanceof Two)
        System.out.println("I get your point!");
        p = (Point)e;  // compile-time error
    }
 }
}
```

This program results in two compile-time errors. The cast `(Point)e` is incorrect because no instance of Element or any of its possible subclasses (none are shown here) could possibly be an instance of any subclass of Point. The `instanceof` expression is incorrect for exactly the same reason. If, on the other hand, the class `Point` were a subclass of `Element`.

Side note: When using the `instanceof` operator, keep in mind that `null` is not an instance of anything.